# How to install QGIS-3 (2.99) on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-3

I tried to install QGIS 3 (2.99) on LUbuntu 17.10, but run into errors.
I tried to follow/adapt the [instructions on QGIS website](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html).

If I add `artful` entries to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu artful main
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly artful main
```

I get `404  Not Found` errors with `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Err:6 http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly artful Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.27.139.220 80]
...
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu artful Release
  404  Not Found
```

If I use `xenial` entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` instead:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly xenial main
```

Then

```
$ sudo apt-get install qgis
```

I get errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
...
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: libgsl2 but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-analysis2.99.0 but it is not going to be installed
        ...
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:2.99.0+git20171103+c9ee3ef+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

*Any suggestions on how to install QGIS3 on Ubuntu 17.10?*

-- Edit --

By the way, I've also tried to use Debian directly:

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
```

But it also gives an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qgis
Reading package lists... Done
...
Some packages could not be installed. 
...
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not installable
        Depends: libgsl0ldbl (>= 1.9) but it is not installable
        ...
        Depends: python-qgis (= 1:2.18.14+13jessie) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:2.18.14+13jessie) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-provider-grass but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Closely related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260659/install-qgis-ubuntugis-on-ubuntu-17-10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what worked for me for qgis3 (2.99):

Add following to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove previous qgis entries

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian-nightly artful main 
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly artful main
```

Then, in command-line:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
```

I had to use `debian-nightly` and also `apt-key` to get it work.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntugis is not provided for higher than xenial and is not needed for Qgis 2.99 unless you have xenial or older. There may be an update to ubuntugis when the next ltr of Ubuntu comes out (18.04)

http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly/dists/

Just use the regular debian repository to install qgis.

Comment: regular debian repository doesn't work for me either. Please see the edit.

Comment: That's because you have used the codename for a debian edition instead of a Ubuntu edition. The debian repository is for both Debian and Ubuntu, the packages for both are there under the same repository path.

Comment: As a sidenote, you **MUST** use ubuntugis if you want QGIS 2.99 on xenial, see https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#id16 . And no chance for trusty and precise.