# Installing QGIS on Ubuntu xenial - QGIS nightly repo?

Tags: qgis, installation, linux

I'm having major problems installing QGIS3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system...

I followed a recently posted [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261503/how-to-install-qgis-3-2-99-on-ubuntu-17-10). Even after adding the `deb qgis.org xxx` line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, the only thing it installs is a really old one, QGIS 2.8.

I also tried to edit the sources file to only contain `https://qgis.org/debian-nightly/`. I tried the following sequence of commands on a) a fresh (was acutally a fresh install) and b) a fully commented `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://qgis.org/debian-nightly xenial main " >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly xenial main " >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

For a): QGIS 2.8 was installed

For b): `Package 'qgis' has no installation candidate`

I just switched to Linux from Win, so I might not know all the tricks.. I also saw [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/124174/how-can-i-specify-the-repository-from-which-a-package-will-be-installed-emacs) on how to specify the repository when you're installing smth. I didn't really understand how to make this work with the QGIS nightly repo: `sudo apt-get install -t xenial qgis`?! I don't think so..

Is anyone patient enough to quickly outline the steps for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, I have the following in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:

```
# deb http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main 
#deb http://qgis.org/debian-nightly/ xenial main
#deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly/ xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly xenial main
```

This leads to being offered a new nightly QGIS build of 2.99 every morning (or so) in the update manager.

Comment: Thx, that worked. Note for future reference, you'll have to install the public key for the PPA: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 089EBE08314DF160`. And probably do some dependency cleanup, depending on what you tried before...

Comment: This helped me out also. Cheers.